# How to convert a NumPy (k,n,m)-size ndarray into a (k)-size dttype=object ndarray of (n,m)-size ndarrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, object, dtype

I have a NumPy ndarray A of size (k,n,m) of int, representing k images each of size nxm pixels.
I would like to convert it into a dtype=object ndarray B of size (k,) containing each of the individual images as ndarrays of size (n,m).

I can do it with a for-loop (below), but is there a more elegant/straightforward way?

```
A = np.arange(2*3*4).reshape(2,3,4)

B = np.empty(A.shape[0],dtype=object)
for i in range(0,A.shape[0]):
    B[i] = A[i]

print(B)

array([array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
              [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
              [ 8,  9, 10, 11]]), array([[12, 13, 14, 15],
                                         [16, 17, 18, 19],
                                         [20, 21, 22, 23]])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: `B[:]=list(A)` might work.  Avoiding broadcasting errors in such an assignment can be tricky.  This might not be any faster since action basically the same.

Answer (score 2):

Your arrays:

```
In [37]: A = np.arange(2*3*4).reshape(2,3,4)
    ...: 
    ...: B = np.empty(A.shape[0],dtype=object)
    ...: for i in range(0,A.shape[0]):
    ...:     B[i] = A[i]
    ...: 
In [38]: B
Out[38]: 
array([array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
              [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
              [ 8,  9, 10, 11]]), array([[12, 13, 14, 15],
                                         [16, 17, 18, 19],
                                         [20, 21, 22, 23]])], dtype=object)
```

Alternate way of assigning `A` to `B`.  Shorter, but not necessarily faster.

```
In [39]: B[:]=list(A)
In [40]: B
Out[40]: 
array([array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
              [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
              [ 8,  9, 10, 11]]), array([[12, 13, 14, 15],
                                         [16, 17, 18, 19],
                                         [20, 21, 22, 23]])], dtype=object)
```

Direct assignment does not work; it has to be a list of arrays, not an array:

```
In [41]: B[:]=A
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-41-b3ca91787565>", line 1, in <module>
    B[:]=A
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,3,4) into shape (2,)
```

The other answer does not work:

```
In [42]: np.array([*A], dtype=object)
Out[42]: 
array([[[0, 1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6, 7],
        [8, 9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: do you see a way to do this using the np.array construction? perhaps by specifying the size of the dtype ?

Comment: Why would I give this answer if there was "better" one? :(   You don't seem to appreciate how close object dtype arrays to lists.

Comment: `object` dtype doesn't take a 'size'.  It just specifies a object pointer, the same sort of thing that a list contains.

Comment: thanks! though object ndarray, unlike lists, to have a shape

Comment: `np.array` doesn't take a `shape`, only a `ndmin`.  `np.array` tries to make as high a dimensional array as it can, as shown by the other answer. So we have to specify the desired array shape first.  `np.array` is a high level function that hides a lot of logic.  `np.ndarray` is the low level constructor, but we don't normally use it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use unpacking instead to get cleaner code:

```
B = np.array([*A], dtype=object)
```

**EDIT: This does not work as the inner elements also gets turned into object type.**

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: Yes I have tested it, the result was the same. I noticed a typo, I have mended it now

Comment: See the test in my answer.

Comment: Yes you're correct, this doesn't work as the inner arrays also gets turned into objects as well (i missed that). My mistake, thank you the correction.